# error showing a part page when deploying to cpanel using nextjs + tailwindcss

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, cpanel, tailwind-css

I'am facing an issue when deployed my website to cpanel using tailwindcss and nextjs. this is for that URL : http://invinitee.id/.

I don't know why when at dev mode in localhost it still normal as you can see below :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edvjg.png)

but when I deployed to cpanel, suddenly a part of page change like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8C0j.png)

after see at inspect element, I see that occured wrapping a part of layout :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grYX1.png)

this is for script when I developed my website.

next.config.js

```html
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const nextConfig = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        use: ["next-images"]
      }
    );
    
    return config;
  },
  // trailingSlash: true,
  // basePath: '/test'
}

module.exports = withPlugins([
  [withTM],
], nextConfig);
```

package.json

```html
{
  "name": "invinitee-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "repository": "https://github.com/Invinitee-IT/invinitee-frontend",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.15.3",
    "@next-tools/dynamic": "^0.0.11",
    "@popperjs/core": "2.9.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "0.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "cookies": "^0.8.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.27.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.9.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.10",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.8",
    "html-to-draftjs": "^1.5.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "next": "^12.0.4",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-images": "^1.8.1",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^8.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "rc-progress": "^3.1.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-animate-height": "^2.0.23",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.2",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.1.1",
    "react-modal-video": "^1.2.8",
    "react-player": "^2.9.0",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.22",
    "react-responsive-modal": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-toggle": "^4.1.2",
    "reactcss": "^1.2.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "video-react": "^0.14.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.4",
    "yargs": "^17.2.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "next lint",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "export": "next export",
    "legacy-install" : "npm install --legacy-peer-deps",
    "force-install" : "npm install --force"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/jit": "^0.1.18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19"
  }
}
```

server.js

```html
const {
    createServer
} = require("http");

const {
    parse
} = require("url");

const next = require("next");
  
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  
  // Create the Express-Next App
const app = next({
   dev:false
});

const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
  
app
    .prepare()
    .then(() => {
        createServer((req, res) => {
            const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
            const {
                pathname,
                query
            } = parsedUrl;
            
            handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
            
            console.log("pathname", pathname);
        }).listen(port, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
        });
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
      console.error(ex.stack);
      process.exit(1);
    });
```

_app.js

```html
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";
import Router, { useRouter } from "next/router";

import PageChange from "components/PageChange/PageChange.js";

import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "react-toggle/style.css";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "../styles/index.css";
import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import "../styles/modal.css";   
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";

Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => {
  document.body.classList.add("body-page-transition");
  ReactDOM.render(
    <PageChange />,
    document.getElementById("page-transition")
  );
});
Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => {
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById("page-transition"));
  document.body.classList.remove("body-page-transition");
});
Router.events.on("routeChangeError", () => {
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById("page-transition"));
  document.body.classList.remove("body-page-transition");
});

export default class MyApp extends App {

  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx : { req, res } }) {
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    return { pageProps };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    const Layout = Component.layout || (({ children }) => <>{children}</>);

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Head>
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
          />
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <base href="/" />
          <link href="/img/logo.jpg" rel="shortcut icon" />
          <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>
          <link
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,300,600,400italic,900 font-semibold"
              rel="stylesheet"
              type="text/css"
          />
          <link
              href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sacramento"
              rel="stylesheet"
          />
        </Head>
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

// MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ req, res }) => {

//   let cookie = new Cookie(req);
  
//   let token = cookie.get('api_token');
  
//   let id = cookie.get('user_id');

//   console.log("hai");

//   if(token && id){
//       address.get(`/v1/client/getclient/${id}`,{
//         headers: {
//           Authorization : `Bearer ${token}`,
//         }
//       })
//       .then(res => console.log(res))
//       .catch(() => null)
//   }
// }
```

_document.js

```html
import React from "react";
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage

    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        // useful for wrapping the whole react tree
        enhanceApp: (App) => App,
        // useful for wrapping in a per-page basis
        enhanceComponent: (Component) => Component,
      })

    // Run the parent `getInitialProps`, it now includes the custom `renderPage`
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)

    return initialProps
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/logo.ico" />
          <link
            rel="apple-touch-icon"
            sizes="76x76"
            href="/img/logo.ico"
          />
        </Head>
        <body className="text-blueGray-700 antialiased">
          <div id="page-transition"></div>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

can you give me solution why that's happened? I'am very stuck just want to find that solution. Anyone who help me will be appreciated..

Comment: are you sure that you're running the same nodejs version on cpanel as on your local computer?

Comment: no, in my localhost I'm using nodejs version 16.13.0 but in cpanel using 14.18. I'm trying to use same version in cpanel but can't npm install because some error. so I'm using nodejs version 14.18. @BogdanStoica

Comment: @0141iii try installing https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm on your local machine and running the site locally with version 14.18 and see what happens